# Instance child class in abstract static method

Tags: php, class, inheritance

I'm quite new to php, I would like to instance a child class from a static method from an abstract parent class. Is it's possible in php or not ?

Here is what I do :

Parent Class :

```php
<?php

namespace App\views;


abstract class Views
{
    protected $template_name = '';

    abstract protected function Get();

    public static function as_view($target = null, $params = null) {
        // Here is this trick
        $create = function () {
            $cls = get_called_class();
            return new $$cls();
        };
        $instance = $create();
        $instance->Get();
    }

    public static function get_template() {
        return self::$template_name;
    }

}
```

Child Class :

```php
<?php

namespace App\views;

use App\views\Views;

class HomeViews extends Views {
    protected $template_name = 'home.html';

    protected function Get() {
        echo self::get_template();
        dump($this);
    }
}
```

And I would like use it like this :

```
<?php

use App\views\HomeView;

HomeView::as_view();
```

But php throw Error :

```
[Thu Sep 24 16:23:50 2020] 127.0.0.1:57001 [200]: / - Uncaught Error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in /Users/dev/PhpstormProjects/my_project/devel/src/views/Views.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/dev/PhpstormProjects/my_project/devel/src/views/Views.php(19): App\views\Views::App\views\{closure}()
#1 /Users/dev/PhpstormProjects/my_project/devel/public/index.php(9): App\views\Views::as_view()
#2 {main}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `$template_name` should be `static`, if you want to use it from a static method.

You can use [late static bindings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) to access static methods and fields from the parent class:

```
<?php

abstract class Views
{
    protected static $template_name = '';

    abstract protected function Get();

    public static function as_view($target = null, $params = null) {
       $instance = new static();
       $instance->Get();
    }

    public static function get_template() {
        return static::$template_name;
    }

}
class HomeViews extends Views {
    protected static $template_name = 'home.html';

    protected function Get() {
        echo self::get_template() . "\n";
        var_dump($this);
    }
}

HomeViews::as_view();
/* outputs:
home.html
object(HomeViews)#1 (0) {
}
*/
```

Comment: @MagnusEriksson if you use `static::` then it depends on the class.

Comment: Wonderfull, perfect ! thx Bro !!!  Didn't know that static() can be used !!

Comment: U made my day ! I love U !